# Switching 'net' Command Output Language in Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, language

## Main Question (command language output)

- How can I convert the output or account/group names to English?

### Additional bonus related questions

- Why are there "aliases" mentioned in the `net localgroup` command output?
- What does the `*` symbol signify in front of group names in the `net user` and `net localgroup` commands?

### Scenario Context

I just installed a `Windows-11 Home` edition **provided in Spanish**. I then wanted it in English, I (seemingly?) managed to migrate almost everything into English.

I then, needed the user account to be a local admin for specific functionality to work. However, when I checked the output from the `net` command, I find that the groups are all **still listed in Spanish**.

### Command and Output

```
# net user Administrador

User name                    Administrador
Full Name
Comment                      Cuenta integrada para la administración del equipo o dominio
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               No
Account expires              Never

Password last set            2023-11-23 19:35:43
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          2023-11-23 19:35:43
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   2023-09-22 00:37:51

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administradores
Global Group memberships     *Ninguno

The command completed successfully.

#------------------------------------------------------
# net localgroup
#------------------------------------------------------

Aliases for \\LAPTOP-XXX

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*Administradores
*Device Owners
*Hyper-V Administrators
*IIS_IUSRS
*Invitados
*Lectores del registro de eventos
*System Managed Accounts Group
*Usuarios
*Usuarios COM distribuidos
*Usuarios de administración remota
*Usuarios del monitor de sistema
*Usuarios del registro de rendimiento

The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: `1.` Why are you voting to close this? Please explain what is the problem?
`2.` I have already tried the above suggestions and problems are (at least) 2. (a) all group related results from are still in Spanish (`es-ES`), and (b) all junction folders are also shown duplicated in Spanish. I'll try to do the `desktop.ini` cleanup, to rid them...

Comment: I'm starting to think that all *groups* and *accounts* (like `Administrador`), where created by the oobe windows image and now need to be renamed, if possible, or else recreated. Not sure windows would like that though.  Any thoughts?  Are there any known workarounds for this?

Comment: Close votes are likely because you're asking 3 questions here. Due to how this site is constructed we ask that each post have only a single question in it.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle True; like music2myear says it is a flaw of superuser, not the question.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Or, you know, we add something to the rules similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ignore_all_rules

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thank you, I just changed admin user name, and so far no bad effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I convert the output or account/group names to English?

You'll have to do it yourself, unfortunately, as it seems that the names as well as the descriptions of *built-in* user and group accounts (such as `Administrator` and `Administrators` in English) are *statically localized* based on the Windows display language *that the OS came with*.

Note:

- Changing account names can obviously break existing code.
- It is unfortunate that Windows localizes these account names to begin with.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567895/45375) shows a programmatic way to do so, which is easiest to perform if have PowerShell remoting access to a machine where the names and description are in the desired language.

---

> Why are there "aliases" mentioned in the net localgroup command output?

As also stated in the linked answer, the term *alias* in the output from `net localgroup` is somewhat misleading, as it simply refers to the *name* of a group (which you can conceive of as being an alias of a group's *unchanging* identifier, the [SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers)).

> What does the `*` symbol signify in front of group names in the net user and net localgroup commands?

While the [`net localgroup` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc725622(v=ws.11)) offers no clue with respect to *local* groups, there is a pointer in the [`net group` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc754051(v=ws.11)), with respect to *domain* user groups (emphasis added):

> `net group` precedes *groups that include both users and groups* with an asterisk (`*`).

However, this logic does *not* also apply to `net localgroup`'s output, where seemingly *every* local group, irrespective of its members or absence thereof - is prefixed with `*`

Therefore, given that you cannot nest *local* groups, my guess is that the use of `*` in this case is a *bug*<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1] [This answers.microsoft.com post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-nest-local-group-with-another-local-group/b087e10c-63eb-4e47-a214-1b60eafb2191) states that while `net localgroup` *technically* lets you nest local groups, that nesting *doesn't actually work* in Windows 7 and above. Similarly, the fact that `lusrmgr.msc` GUI does *not* allow you to add a group to another group suggests this limitation.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for, and can only be expected from you. :)